# HTML5 Form Select Field not displaying until hover

Tags: css, html, forms, select

I’m having trouble viewing my drop-down menu items on Windows. When I open the drop-down menu, the choices are hidden until you hover over them. Everything seems to be working fine on Mac (Chrome/Safari), but isn’t working on Windows (Chrome/IE). Has anyone come across this before?

Here’s my HTML:

```
<select>
    <option value disabled selected>Select your option</option>
    <option value=“duck”>Duck</option>
    <option value=“lamb”>Lamb</option>
    <option value=“vegetarian”> Vegetarian </option>
</select>
```

You can view the site in question here:
http://newyearnewshaki.com > click on RSVP button

Comment: Try it on Windows 10 and Chrome... It seems that the options below the first one are stylished with white color so, doesn' appear as expected but here... Just remove or change the rule and... your options will appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have a CSS rule that sets the font color to white. Line 2084:

```
input,textarea,file,select {
    font-family: "Montserrat",sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 1em 0 2em 0;
    font-size: 1em;
    color:#FFF; /* HERE */
    outline: none;
    -webkit-transition: border 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: border 0.2s ease-in-out;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the background-color of your select to black.

Your font is white and you background-color is also white, the text only shows when you hover, because you hover change the background-color to gray.